# Convert GMT NSDate to device's current Time Zone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com to store some values:

[image]

These are GMT values. How do I convert these to the device's current time zone and get NSDate as a result?

Comment: This question has been answered a dozen times S.O. Just search for 'iOS GMT to Local' - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS+GMT+to+Local

Comment: Oscar, be sure to mark one of the many answers below as accepted. That way the community knows which of them resolved your issue.

Comment: @Aaron, sure! I'm testing :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

NSDate is always represented in GMT. It's just how you represent it that may change.

If you want to print the date to `label.text`, then convert it to a string using `NSDateFormatter` and `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]`, as follows:

```
NSString *gmtDateString = @"08/12/2013 21:01";

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

//Create the date assuming the given string is in GMT
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:gmtDateString];

//Create a date string in the local timezone
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone].secondsFromGMT];
NSString *localDateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"date = %@", localDateString);

// My local timezone is: Europe/London (GMT+01:00) offset 3600 (Daylight)
// prints out: date = 08/12/2013 22:01
```

Comment: It is that `NSDate`s simply don't have time zones (or hours, days, etc.); they are just points in time. The `NSDate` for what a Londoner would call 5:30 PM is exactly the same as the `NSDate` for 9:30 AM in Cupertino, CA.

Comment: I understand the concept but what I was missing is the timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: this is the actual trick, thank you :)

Answer (score 25):

The easiest method I've found is this:

```
NSDate *someDateInUTC = …;
NSTimeInterval timeZoneSeconds = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
NSDate *dateInLocalTimezone = [someDateInUTC dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneSeconds];
```

Comment: The concept worked for me but I had to do the following: `[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:-timeZoneSeconds sinceDate:someDateInUTC];` (Tested with PST timezone.)

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I searched for quite some time, and it seems most people are concerned about outputing into strings vs performing date logic specific to the user's locale.

Comment: This logic will have issue with dates observing day light saving

Answer (score 5):

This is a very clean way to change the NSDate to a local time zone date

```
extension NSDate {

    func toLocalTime() -> NSDate {

        let timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

        let seconds : TimeInterval = Double(timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for:self as Date))

        let localDate = NSDate(timeInterval: seconds, since: self as Date)
        return localDate
    }
}
```

taken from https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/how-to-convert-nsdate-to-different-time-zones/

Answer (score 3):

Creating an Xcode test case like the following may help us remember the rules "forever":

```
- (void)test2015_05_23_07_07_07_Toronto {
    NSString *utcDateString = @"2015_05_23 12:07:07";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss";

    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    NSDate *date2015_05_23_12_07_07_UTC = [dateFormatter dateFromString:utcDateString];

    XCTAssertTrue([date2015_05_23_12_07_07_UTC.description isEqualToString:@"2015-05-23 12:07:07 +0000"]);

    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
    NSString *torontoDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date2015_05_23_12_07_07_UTC];
    XCTAssertTrue([torontoDateString isEqualToString:@"2015_05_23 07:07:07"]);

    // change format to add ZZZ
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
    torontoDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date2015_05_23_12_07_07_UTC];
    XCTAssertTrue([torontoDateString isEqualToString:@"2015_05_23 07:07:07 -0500"]);

    XCTAssertEqual(1432382827, [date2015_05_23_12_07_07_UTC timeIntervalSince1970]);

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:date2015_05_23_12_07_07_UTC];
    XCTAssertEqual(2015, components.year);
    XCTAssertEqual(5, components.month);
    XCTAssertEqual(23, components.day);
    XCTAssertEqual(7, components.hour);
    XCTAssertEqual(7, components.minute);
    XCTAssertEqual(7, components.second);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a NSDateFormatter to achieve this result.

```
NSString *dateAsString = @"08/07/2013 04:06";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[df setTimeZone:gmt];

NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: dateAsString];

NSLog(@"date: %@", myDate);
```

Comment: Sure! However, myDate would still be in GMT, and I want it to be in the device's current Time Zone.

Comment: @NSMutableString, This solution works but it does not change the myDate locale / timezone to the desired locale / timezone. Your solution will change / format the dateAsString to a date in GMT format.

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers to this question but I would recommend this one:

[Convert GMT NSDate to device's current Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107782/ios-convert-gmt-nsdate-to-devices-current-time-zone)

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2012-07-16 07:33:01";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; 
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"date : %@",date);

NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; // <- Local time zone
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date1];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date1];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

NSDate *destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval    sinceDate:date1] autorelease];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"];
[dateFormatters setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatters setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatters setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
[dateFormatters setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];  
dateStr = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];
NSLog(@"DateString : %@", dateStr);
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but what is wrong with mine below? It's 5 lines of code and does the same thing.