# How to compare the date which is come from server with [NSDate date] in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdateformatter

I'm getting the date string from server in *01/02/2014 16:43:00 AM* format, which is having *GMT timeZone*.

I've to compare that date with current date for live streaming. If the current date is lesser than that server date I've to show some alert which shows the correct live starting time. *But I'm not able to compare them*.

How to convert that server date string to date format and how to compare that date with current date ?

I'm using the following code :

```
NSString *DateFromServer = video.Eventutcstart;
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString *tzName = [timeZone name];
[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:tzName]];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSString *str = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:str];
NSDate *serverDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString: DateFromServer];
NSLog(@"currentDate %@", currentDate);
NSLog(@"serverDate %@", serverDate);
NSComparisonResult result;

result = [currentDate compare:serverDate]; 

if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"alert message");
}
```

output:

```
2014-01-03 11:30:25.346 VMS[955:70b] currentDate 2014-01-02 19:00:23 +0000

2014-01-03 11:30:32.088 VMS[955:70b] serverDate 2014-01-02 19:00:46 +0000
```

Please help me to solve this....

Comment: what is output of `NSLog(@"currentDate %@", currentDate);
NSLog(@"serverDate %@", serverDate);` ?

Comment: Yes please provide output of logs so someone can help you

Comment: Check this that might be helpful to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107782/convert-gmt-nsdate-to-devices-current-time-zone

Comment: please also compare the date values in the debug console. On the left side of the debug console, u will see 1 date (GMT date) and the log will give u 1 date according to the system timezone.. So please check carefully. I had faced similar issues, and then realized when i saw the two values as different

Comment: i test the code but there is no issue on my side. i get "alert message" print on my console.

Comment: @iOS.Wolf i'm also getting but after that server time happen also i'm getting the alert message. It should not print that message after that server time.

Comment: when server date is grate then current date then you want to "alert message" ?? right ??

Comment: yes if it is greater than currentdate , I've to show alert  @iOS.Wolf

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code. You were not setting timezone correctly:

```
NSString *DateFromServer = video.Eventutcstart;
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSString *str = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:str];
NSDate *serverDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString: DateFromServer];
NSLog(@"currentDate %@", currentDate);
NSLog(@"serverDate %@", serverDate);
NSComparisonResult result;

result = [currentDate compare:serverDate];

if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"alert message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For date comparison only**, 
You have two dates correctly obtained so can use :

```
int days1 = [currentDate timeIntervalSince1970] / 86400;
int days2 = [serverDate timeIntervalSince1970] / 86400;
if(days1==days2)
 {
   //do something;
 }
else
 {
   //do something
 }
```

Above code does not takes time in consideration and compares only year/month/day

**For NSdate time comparison**

```
unsigned int flags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents* component1 = [calendar components:flags fromDate:currentDate];
NSDateComponents* component2 = [calendar components:flags fromDate:serverDate];


NSDate* currentDateTimeOnly = [calendar dateFromComponents:component1];
NSDate* serverDateTimeOnly = [calendar dateFromComponents:component2];

NSComparisonResult result;

result = [currentDateTimeOnly compare:serverDateTimeOnly];

if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"alert message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if(result == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSLog(@"alert message");
}
```

instead of this one

```
if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"alert message");
}
```

if you want to check both constraint with both date then you can use bellow code.

```
if(result == NSOrderedAscending){
    NSLog(@"serverDate is in the future");
}else if(result == NSOrderedDescending){
    NSLog(@"serverDate is in the past");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Both dates are the same");
}
```

Comment: In this case, if the current date is less than server date also it is not going to the condition

Comment: but in if condition you can check only one constraint whether current is grater then server date or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];


NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *a1=[def objectForKey:@"Currentdate"];
NSDate *now = [dateFormat dateFromString:a1];

NSDate * currentdate = [NSDate date];
NSString *nowstr=[dateFormat stringFromDate:currentdate];
    NSDate *todaydate=[dateFormat dateFromString:nowstr];

NSLog(@"Now is %@ and current date is %@",[def objectForKey:@"Currentdate"],nowstr);
NSComparisonResult result = [todaydate compare:now];

switch (result)
{
    case NSOrderedAscending:
        dateiswhich=-1;
        NSLog(@"%@ is in future from %@", currentdate, now);
        break;
    case NSOrderedDescending:
        dateiswhich=1;
        NSLog(@"%@ is in past from %@", currentdate, now);
        break;
    case NSOrderedSame: dateiswhich=-1;

        break;
    default: NSLog(@"erorr dates %@, %@", currentdate, now); break;
}
```

use above code might be useful to you