# Iterating over a year to get each days NSDate object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Hello I have a method that returns an array of times for each day.

```
prayTimesDate(date: NSDate, latitide : Double, longitude : Double, timeZone : Double) -> NSMutableArray
```

I need to iterate through a whole year or maybe a date range to get an array of times for each day in a whole year. I found alot of references in ruby and python on how to do this but I couldn't find anything for swift or objective-c. Is there any built in methods in swift that will accomplish this? If not can someone help me out as I am still new in programming. Any input is greatly appreciated.

This is the objective-c code for the method I'm linking to my swift project

```
- (NSMutableArray *)prayerTimesDate:(NSDate *)date latitude:(double)latitude longitude:(double)longitude andTimezone:(double)timezone
{
    unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

    NSInteger year = [components year];
    NSInteger month = [components month];
    NSInteger day = [components day];

    return [self getDatePrayerTimesForYear:year month:month day:day latitude:latitude longitude:longitude andtimeZone:timezone];
}
```

Comment: What code is currently in your prayTimesDate method?

Comment: @ Lyndsey Scott I just updated my question

Comment: to clarify my question I just need a way to iterate from the current day all the way to a year eveytime the user opens the app so I can update the prayer time tables.

Comment: And have you written anything in your getDatePrayerTimesForYear method yet?

Comment: Also, did you want the code in Swift or Obj-C? I gather that you want it in Swift... But what's the Obj-C method for?

Comment: And, most importantly, what times exactly do you want in each days array? Do you just want an array containing midnight of each day for example?

Comment: yes i would like it in swift of course. The method above already returns the correct times for a giving date. It returns an array of strings of the seven prayer times depending on your location and time zone. what I'm trying to do is use this method to not only get one days prayer array but for the whole year from the current day.

Comment: say for example today is 01/24/2015 I want to get an array of each days prayers of each month until 01/24/2016

Comment: I wish people would comment before down voting so we can learn from our mistakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your `prayerTimesDate:` method is already returning the expected result, you can loop through each day of the year while repeatedly call `prayerTimesDate:` to get an array containing the prayer times for each day, ex:

```
func yearlyPrayerDatesFromCurrentDate (latitude:Double, longitude:Double, timezone:Double) -> NSMutableArray {

    // Set "date" to equal the current day
    var date:NSDate! = NSDate()

    // Increment "date" by one year to calculate the ending
    // date for the loop
    let gregorian:NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = 1
    let endingDate:NSDate! = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: date, options: nil)

    // Create an array to hold *all* the returned 
    // results for the year
    var datesArray = NSMutableArray()

    // Loop through each date until the ending date is
    // reached
    while date.compare(endingDate) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
        // Call your prayerTimesDate: method on the current
        // date to get that date's prayer times and add the
        // times from the returned array to the datesArray
        datesArray.addObjectsFromArray(prayerTimesDate(date, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, andTimezone: timezone))

        // increment the date by 1 day
        let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = 1
        date = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: date, options: nil)
    }

    return datesArray
}
```

Comment: ok so I just edited the code to datesArray.addObject instead of addObjectsFormArray so I can have each date in its own seperate array then I added datesArray.addObject(date) so I can have a date to identify each array. But the first date is always one day ahead ex. 01/25/2015

Comment: I even added the date before the while loop to get the current date and then I added it again in the while loop after the addObjects

Comment: @GhassanMohammed It's currently 1/25/2015 in the GMT timezone and that's the timezone for any NSDate object.

Comment: oh i c. Excuse my ignorance but should I change the date component to default time zone would that give me the correct date?

Comment: You should probably just return your prayerTimesDate dates in GMT, but here are a few solutions that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18107782/2274694

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example for a period over 14 days (without NSCalendar):

```
let ti:NSTimeInterval = 24*60*60 //one day
let dateFrom = NSDate() //Now
let dateTo = dateFrom.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24*60*60*14) //14 Days later

var nextDate = NSDate()
var endDate = dateTo.dateByAddingTimeInterval(ti)

while nextDate.compare(endDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
{      
    print("nextDate:", nextDate)
    nextDate = nextDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(ti)
}
```

Comment: due to Daylight Saving Times days do not necessarily have 24 hours. they might be 23, 24 or 25 hours long. as the last result is used to compute the next one, the error will not only be in 2 days in a year but up to the half of it.

Comment: a must see for every iOS/macOS developer: [WWDC11: Performing Calendar Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/117/)

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSDateComponents` instance for 1 day and `NSDate` objects for each time on the first day. Now you can iterate over the number of days you want (or until you hit then end date) and then you can use `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` of the calendar to get the new date for each day.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple doc: To compute a sequence of dates, use the enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate:matchingComponents:options:usingBlock: method instead of calling this method ( - nextDateAfterDate:matchingComponents:options: ) in a loop with the previous loop iteration's result.

As I got, it will iterate all dates that matched with "matchingComponents" till you finish iteration with "stop.memory = true"

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let startDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
let finishDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 10, toDate: startDate, options: [])
let dayComponent = NSDateComponents()
dayComponent.hour = 1

calendar.enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate(startDate, matchingComponents: dayComponent, options: [.MatchStrictly]) { (date, exactMatch, stop) in
    print(date)
    if date!.compare(finishDate!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
        // .memory gets at the value of an UnsafeMutablePointer
        stop.memory = true
    }
}
```