# NSDate formatter iOS and TimeAgo with server parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I try get a date of string:

```
NSLog(@"DATE: %@", obj[@"createdAt"]);
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'";
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"revert DATE: %@", date);
```

but I get this:

```
DATE:     2015-07-07T04:51:28.227Z

revert DATE: 2015-07-07 09:21:28 +0000
```

I change the locale but not working.

when try use [TimeAgo.h](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo) He tells me four hours instead of right now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a debugging issue; your parsing looks OK.

When logging the date using `%@` from `NSLog()` the `[NSDate description]` method is used to "print" the date and that is always printed in UTC.

You simply need to use the `NSDateFormatter` to show the contents of the `NSDate` object.

Answer (score 0):

I lacked only this line:

```
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

Thanks to: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107782/convert-gmt-nsdate-to-devices-current-time-zone)