# Converting NSDate from UTC to local gives wrong result

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I am creating an NSDate from components of hour and minute. It is in GMT and prints correctly as:

```
0001-01-01 07:30:00 +0000
```

I then want to convert this to my local timezone (CET), so I set up the NSDateFormatter like so:

```
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
```

This prints (using `.Longstyle`):

```
08.13.00 GMT+0.43
```

This is wrong—it is supposed to be GMT+1. Printing the `.localTimeZone()` gives the correct offset:

```
Local Time Zone (Europe/Oslo (CET) offset 3600)
```

---

**Edit1:** By adding this extension(from an answer linked in comments) to NSDate, I can offset the timezone by hand. But then I need to set the NSDateFormatter timezone to GMT, which I don't think is right.

```
extension NSDate {
  func toLocalTime() -> NSDate {    
    let timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    let seconds : NSTimeInterval = Double(timeZone.secondsFromGMTForDate(self))      
    let localDate = NSDate(timeInterval: seconds, sinceDate: self)
    return localDate
  }
}
```

---

**Edit2:** I made a test project. The expected output is for the time printed to match the offset in the timezone. Instead it adds 43 minutes.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let realDateComponents = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: NSDate())
    guard let realDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(realDateComponents)
        else{fatalError("Unable to get real date.")}
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle

    print(realDate)
    print(formatter.stringFromDate(realDate))
    print(NSTimeZone.localTimeZone())
}

// OUTPUT
0001-01-01 21:03:00 +0000
21.46
Local Time Zone (Europe/Oslo (CET) offset 3600)
```

Comment: Have you taken look at-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107782/convert-gmt-nsdate-to-devices-current-time-zone

Comment: I've read several of the questions about doing the conversion, but I still don't understand why NSDateFormatter wants to use GMT+0.43 instead of GMT+1. I must be making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Look at your year 0001. You need to post how you are creating your date from components

Comment: The date is created by `let date = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: NSDate())`.

Comment: Can you include the full code from your `NSDate` up until you get `GMT+0.43`? It's a little hard to make sense of it from the fragments you've included so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any
>   particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are
>   immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an
>   absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).

Apparently you're creating the date from the `.Hour` and `.Minute` components, that sets the (indeterminate) year information to 01 (not 2001).

The point in time about 2000 years ago is a pretty large time interval which probably causes the weird behavior.

Comment: It does make sense with your explanation. I have tested simply adding a `.Year` to my components and it did the trick. Many thanks for helping out!

Comment: In hindsight I think it is obvious that working in year 1 (especially on month 1, day 1) is something that could cause the fabric of time to misbehave, but in my defense I naively assumed the defaults would be safe.